# How to override views components in filament

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm wanting to override a filament component that is in the Filament Vendor. Does anyone indicate any material, or have you done, could you give a help?
The component is in the following directory, I want to edit, I tried several things but I couldn't

```php
@props([
    'navigation',
])
<!-- override this file
//vendor/filament/filament/resources/views/components/page/sub-navigation/sidebar.blade.php
-->
<ul
    wire:ignore
    {{ $attributes->class(['hidden w-72 flex-col gap-y-7 md:flex']) }}
>
    @foreach ($navigation as $navigationGroup)
        <x-filament-panels::sidebar.group
            :collapsible="$navigationGroup->isCollapsible()"
            :icon="$navigationGroup->getIcon()"
            :items="$navigationGroup->getItems()"
            :label="$navigationGroup->getLabel()"
            :sidebar-collapsible="false"
        />
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This component is called on this page

```php
//vendor/filament/filament/resources/views/components/page/index.blade.php

...
  <x-filament-panels::page.sub-navigation.sidebar
             :navigation="$subNavigation"
   />
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information provided on

[FilamentPHP: Adding some style · Laravel Bytes](https://fly.io/laravel-bytes/filamentphp-adding-some-style/)

and the

[Override account widget · filamentphp/filament · Discussion #8752](https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/8752#discussioncomment-7126870)

You can attempt customization by creating a `resources/views/vendor/filament-panels/components/page/sub-navigation/sidebar.blade.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Ying-Shang Lin, I spent several hours and days trying to solve this problem, but I had no idea how to solve. My mistake was to have put the file on the wrong directory.    
 
I was putting in this directory:    
`resources/views/vendor/filament/components/page/subnavigation/sidebar.blade.php`  <br/>

The correct one is in this:      
`resources/views/vendor/filament-panels/components/page/subnavigation/sidebar.blade.php`